# website to receive file upload from winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, upload

I need to upload a file from a winform application to a website.

I have the winform side ready to go, I just need a little help with the webform side.

```
 Client.UploadFile("http://xxx.yyy.com/data/", "sample.txt");
```

The file(s) that are to be uploaded, binary files, just need to be dumped into a subdirectory called data

I am stuck on the web page that will receive the file and save it into the directory.

c# and asp.net please

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a web page for accepting the file being sent to server. Probably the easiest way would be to set up ftp on server and upload file there.

Sample code from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx